# Как найти ближайшие 2 точки QPointF к позиции курсора на карте?

Tags: c++, qt5

У меня есть многоугольник, когда я навожу курсор мыши на этот многоугольник, то я пытаюсь найти ближайшие две координаты к этой позиции мыши. Все вершины многоугольника у меня хранятся в векторе

```
QVector<QPointF> points;
```

Также сам курсор мыши у меня есть как QPointF. Сейчас я пытаюсь найти ближайшие точки к этой позиции, но не совсем понимаю как сделать это корректно и оптимально.

P.s. под ближайшими точками я подразумеваю именно 2 точки, которые в пересечении с позицией курсора мыши будут образовывать треугольник.

Comment: https://qna.habr.com/q/231913

Comment: Ну, если многоугольник не из 20000 вершин :), то полный перебор будет вполне адекватен - находим все расстояния и выбираем 2 наименьших. Чтоб считать было проще - ищем квадраты расстояний, не беря квадратный корень.

Comment: Любые две точки вместе  с позицией курсора будут образовывать треугольник. Если я правильно понимаю, Вам надо найти две соседние вершины многоугольника? Или две его произвольные точки?

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов, да, мне нужно найти ближайшие 2 вершины мноугольника к позиции курсора.

Comment: Кроме перебора - не вижу варианта. Перебором находим ближайшую вершину, потом проверяем две соседних, выбираем ту, что ближе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как понимаю `ближайшая` точка означает, с наименьшим [евклидовым расстоянием](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%95%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0).

Привожу здесь вариант алгоритма [с соседнего поста](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1222224/267338) только для случая евклидового расстояния до заданной точки (координаты мыши).

```
QPointF mouse; // Fill-in with mouse coordinates.

auto SqrDist = [](QPointF const & a, QPointF const & b) {
    return (a.x() - b.x()) * (a.x() - b.x()) + (a.y() - b.y()) * (a.y() - b.y());
};
size_t min0i = 0, min1i = 1;
auto min0d = SqrDist(mouse, points.at(0)), min1d = SqrDist(mouse, points.at(1));
if (min0d > min1d) {
    std::swap(min0i, min1i); // #include <algorithm>
    std::swap(min0d, min1d);
}
for (size_t i = 2; i < points.size(); ++i) {
    auto d = SqrDist(mouse, points.at(i));
    if (d < min0d) {
        min1i = min0i; min0i = i;
        min1d = min0d; min0d = d;
    } else if (d < min1d) {
        min1i = i; min1d = d;
    }
}
QPointF point_min0 = points.at(min0i), point_min1 = points.at(min1i);
```